# Dynamic Sequencing of data in MS Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

So, I have this Report:

[image: Routing Documents]

And this Query:

[image: Routing Query]

The report pulls all of it's data from the query. The fields STA1, STA2, STA3, and STA4 are from the Job Order table in which each job has an order set based on Work Stations (Named CU01, CU02, BR01...).

I have attempted to make macros that essentially say

> If Reports![Production Router LBPW]![Work Station 1]="CU01" Then Reports![Production Router LBPW]![Run Time 1]=Query![Query Laser Hours by P/N]![Total Laser Hours]

If I understand properly, a series of statements like that could essentially associate each work station with a specific type of time data (Cutting, Bending, Inserting, and Welding), effectively rearranging my fields to automatically display the time data I want in the places I want them. Alas, I don't know enough about macros to make that work and I know even less about VBA. If I can be filled in on a couple lines of code, or something, that would allow me to accomplish this, I'm sure I may be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion from the other question, I would have to change the order of operations to match the part every time I ran the report. It doesn't allow for the order of operations to change, the data will always be pulled in the order I told it to be pulled in when I set up the report.

In short, it appears to me, that your suggestion creates a static sequence of operations without modifying the report everytime I ran a part with a different sequence of operations. I want the sequence on the report to change with the actual sequence in which I perform the operations.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't know enough about this to get much more specific. I can tell you that Cut time, Weld time, Rivet time, and Bend time are all fields that I'm trying to draw from and that I want the fields to be resequenced, not the records, based on an order that I can set for each part, perhaps in another table.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the question with a picture of what I currently have, but I'm not allowed to post it because I don't have enough rep on the website. I need 4 more.

Comment: The problem is that I want the fields to be ordered differently each time I run the report. If at all possible, I would like this resequencing to be automated.

Comment: From your image, it appears that you want to put a different field in position 10,20,30 or 40 according to the ID, one way would be using aliases, so instead of `select weld, this, that ...` you would `select weld as Pos10, this as Pos20, that As pos30` It has got impossible to continue here because SO is not set up for conversations and you do not yet have enough reputation to chat, you can PM me at http://lessthandot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create various queries, for example:

QueryCU01

```
SELECT [Cuttime] As Pos1, [Weldtime] As Pos2, [Rivettime] As Pos3, Bend As Pos4 
FROM JobOrder
```

You report would then refer to Pos1, not CutTime. The labels could also be textboxes, so they update automatically as well, for example:

```
SELECT [Cuttime] As Pos1, "Cut" As lbl1, [Weldtime] As Pos2, "Weld" As lbl2
       [Rivettime] As Pos3, "Rivet" As lbl3, Bend As Pos4 "Bend" As lbl4
FROM JobOrder
```

It is possible that you could simplify further by normalizing your tables.

Tasks table

```
Job   Action Time Machine SortOrder
 1    Cut    10   AB         3
 1    Bend    4   CD         1
 1    Rivet  30   EF         6
```

Comment: If you wish to post sample data, it may be possible to give a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I have found another solution that I think will work swimingly. I'll post it once I have it completed.

Comment: You were right. I was too consumed with getting logic to do it, that I ignored the possibility of rearranging my time tables. The problem was that all of my time data was in a single record. Since I have broken it into many, as you suggested, it was much easier.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've done is use a series of Switch functions in my query so that the data that is pulled into each query is inserted into each field by a logical statement. For operation name, the logic is as follows:

> OP2: Switch([ST2]="PE01","Insert",[ST2]="PE02","Insert",[ST2]="BR01","Bend",[ST2]="BR02","Bend",[ST2]="WE01","Auto Weld",[ST2]="WE02","MIG Weld",[ST2]="WE03","TIG Weld",True,"N/A")

Which essentially means, If ST2=PE01, Then OP2=Insert, elseif ST2=BR01, then OP2=Bend...

Then I set up another swith that says If OP2=Bend, Time2=BendTime... So on and so forth. This way each field contains a value that is entered based on the logical statements and the order of the jobs is determined by the order that I've set when I enterred the station names in the Job Order Table.